# Widget Logic - display on page and all child

Tags: php, menus, widgets, conditional-tags

I have problem with condition function in Widget Logic (worpdress).
I would like to display menu on subpage and all child set to it.

I use this:

```
global $post; return (in_array(1959,get_post_ancestors($post)));
```

In this case it works on all child but no dispaly on subpage (1959).

I try also:

```
global $post; return (is_page('Offer') || ($post->post_parent=="1959"));
```

In this case it doesn't display on deeper child.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need ancestors rather than just parents. That way on deeper pages, you'll be able to determine whether Offer is a grandparent/great-grandparent/etc. page.

```
global $post;
$ancestors = $post->ancestors;
if($ancestors || is_page('Offer')) {
     // your menu here
}
```